# jQuery: Button toggle isn't functioning as intended

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, toggle

I'm just learning jQuery at the moment, and wanted to know if there is possibly a way that I can make my code work? When I click the green button, it doesn't show the second table row. What can I do to avoid this mistake in the future? I'm open to any and all help! Please and thank you.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(".row2").show();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr class="row1">
        <td>
            <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
        </td>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td>
                <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>This is where the text in the boxes will go!</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<a class="greenbuttontext" href="#"><button class="showmorebutton">Show9 more concepts</button></a>
```

css:

```
/*styles for green showmore button*/
 .showmorebutton {
    height: 33px;
    border: solid #628b06 1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #99cd00;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: center;
    line-height: 33px;
}

.greenbuttontext {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*row2 disappear*/
.row2 {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/uk3E3/9/. Probably you didnt refer jquery in your code

Comment: Any error in console? Are you at least correctly including jQuery???

Comment: I ended up removing the anchor tag all together, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html is invalid. button inside in a tag

```
<a class="greenbuttontext" href="#"><button class="showmorebutton">Show
            9 more concepts</button></a>
```

change to

```
<a class="greenbuttontext" href="#"></a>
<button class="showmorebutton">Show
            9 more concepts</button>
```

Note: a tag is inline block element.

Comment: Thank you! This worked 100%! I ended up just getting rid of the anchor tag all together.

Answer (score 0):

Do not wrap the `<button />` in an `<a />` tag? the click event might be triggering on anchor instead of the button.